# Checkout changing branch name with GitHub Actions Step

Tags: github-actions, branch, staging

For the github actions checkout step I need to check out our staging branch.

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout 
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      token: dispatch_token_here
      ref: staging.*
```

The staging branch always starts with `staging.` but the rest changes whenever we cut a new staging branch. For example: `staging.2.22.23`
I have not had success trying to check out the staging branch without hardcoding in the full staging branch, which is less than ideal.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
"staging.*"
staging.*
"staging."
```

Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: You can't use a pattern like that, but you can maybe access the branch name from the event payload. What triggers the workflow to run?

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, your comment got me thinking to look into how to access all the branches and get the one starting with staging.

Answer (score 0):

able to resolve my issue by using git for-each-ref:

```
- name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      token: dispatch_token_here
      fetch-depth: 0
  - name: Get staging branch name
    id: branch_name
    run: echo "staging_branch=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/staging*)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  - name: Checkout staging branch
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      token: dispatch_token_here
      fetch-depth: 0
      ref: ${{ steps.branch_name.outputs.staging_branch }}
```